# Find global optima of $h(x,y)=x^2 y (x-y-1)$ , $1 \leq x \leq 2$, $0 \leq y \leq x-1$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

I need to find the global optima of the function $h(x,y)=x^2 y (x-y-1)$ over the domain $1 \leq x \leq 2$, $0 \leq y \leq x-1$.

To solve this I check the points in the interior of the domain, using the condition $\nabla h(x,y)=0$. All the points I get are outside the interior.

Then I check the boundaries, but this part is giving me doubts.

First, using $y = x-1$, $h(x,y)=x^2 (x-1) (x-(x-1)-1)=0$, so my objective function is $0$.

This also happens with $y=0$. So in this 2 boundaries my objective functions is $0$. And I am not sure what to do. Any help?

Also, using $x=2$ I get the point $(2,\frac{1}{2})$, and with $x=1$ the point $(1,0)$.

Furthermore, Wolfram tells me the global maximum is $(2,\frac{1}{2})$, and the global minimum $(\frac{3}{2},0)$ (a point in the boundary $y=0$). I would like to know how to get the point $(\frac{3}{2},0)$ for the global minimum. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the solution and maybe you and me need an explanation about how WolframAlpha works.

I think the full reasoning is this: the interior has no relative extrema (you proved this), so, the absolute extrema are in the boundary. You get the restriction of $h$ for the boundary and take derivatives. Dividing it in three parts we get

For the line $x=2$

$$h_2(y)=4y(1-y)$$

$$h'=4-8y=0\implies y=1/2$$

A maximum (at $(2,1/2)$) as $h(2,0)=0<1/2$

In each of the other two parts you find a constant function and equal to zero. The minumum value is then zero and is reached in each of the points of these two pieces of the boundary.

I suppose that Wolfram Alpha is forced to pick only one of them. Or something, because I get from WA three points all of them in the line $y=x-1$...